# I'm trying to run a C# program and get the following error

Tags: c#, .net

I just installed VS Code and .Net 6.0 SDK and I'm trying to run a simple code and I get the following. [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCjbP.png)

Comment: Please do not post errors as an image.  Copy and paste the error into your question directly.

Comment: So did you follow the instructions shown in the error to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run your code on .NETCore 5.0, however your machine has .NETCore 6.0 installed and does not accept version 6.0 . You need to match the code requirements.